# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work for me

Tags: 16.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 (through a LIVE-CD), and the installation process went fine. So when I tried to start Ubuntu for the first time, there already was a strange graphical glitch on the top of the screen (there were some green-purple stripes). It also loaded kinda slowly and the login screen also took a few seconds to load correctly (it also was kinda buggy). But, since this was the first boot up of the system I didn't think much about it.

So, signing in also went fine, but for some reason the desktop didn't load. I just saw the wallpaper and I can move my mouse fine, but I can't interact with anything. There was no task bar, no top bar, no nothing. When I right clicked on the desktop a context menu started flimmering up, but since it just was appearing and disappearing within a few milliseconds I couldn't interact with it. I thought I should try to update the driver, so I pressed `STRG + ALT + F1` to force-open the terminal (there was no other way I could open it). And for some reason the Internet doesn't work either, so I couldn't update any driver or software.

If it does matter: I have a GTX 960.

I really hope anyone can help me, I really want to try Ubuntu to get rid of Windows, but it's really frustrating when nothing seems to work. I already reinstalled Ubuntu like 3-times, but that didn't improve my situation.

Comment: When you run it as a live version, everything works fine?

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/781464/edit) your question and add the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -A 9 "NVIDIA"` since you have troubles with your GUI you can as well do this from terminal directly into [paste,ubuntu.com](e.ubuntu.com/) by using this line: `lspci -vnn | grep -A 9 "NVIDIA" | pastebinit` this way you get a link you can put into your question.

Comment: I just tried it, it loads for a while and ends up with a black screen... Had to shut down the power because I couldn't do anything else.

Comment: More hardware specs please. What computer are you using?

Comment: @El3ctroGh0st When you are in your login screen, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to enter a TTY session, there you will have to provide first your user name and your password to log in, then go from there.

Comment: @TheChosenOne99

Operating System
   Windows 10 Home 64-bit

  CPU
   Intel Core i5 6400 @ 2.70GHz 36 °C
   Skylake 14nm Technology

  RAM
   8.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 797MHz (11-11-11-28)

  Motherboard
   HP 2B47 (U3E1) 28 °C

  Graphics
   S27C590 (1920x1080@60Hz)
   2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 (HP) 34 °C

  Storage
   119GB SanDisk SD7SB6S-128G-1006 (SSD) 34 °C
   931GB Western Digital WDC WD10EZEX-60M2NA0 

(SATA) 33 °C

  Optical Drives
   hp HLDS DVDRW GUD0N

  Audio
   USB PnP Sound Device

Sorry for bad formatting, I took that from a program.

Comment: It seems like that it is a graphics card problem.

Comment: @TheChosenOne99 Some way to fix this? Or do I need to wait for a patch and try an older version of Ubuntu? (as Jared Starkey said)

Comment: You might want try an earlier version of Ubuntu. 16.04 is unstable when it comes to with Nvidia and AMD graphics. I keep hearing tales of woe about Nvidia and AMD graphics users having trouble with 16.04 on this site and others.  I recommend using Ubuntu 14.04 for now. It is currently the most stable version of Ubuntu that is still supported.

Comment: Okay, thanks much! I just wanted to say, I managed to run Ubuntu 16.04 (1-2 weeks ago) on VirtualBox, but I guess that's something different, isn't it?

Comment: You might as well have a look at this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: @Videonauth I already tried that! Problem is, as I mentioned before that I can't connect to the W-LAN. (If i try through the terminal it says he doesn't recognize the w-lan card (Atleast I guess that's what it says, lol).

Comment: @El3ctroGh0st do you want to come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) this way we do not create a super long list of comments here.

Comment: @Videonauth So, yesterday I installed Fedora, because I was curious if it would wor or not. When I was in the login windows the mouse was bugging around and after I logged in nothing happened, screen just was grey (I guess it was the desktop background). Isn't it weird that not only Ubuntu but other versions of Linux don't seem to work on my PC. Sorry if I bother you, but I really want to get Linux to work on my PC, I want to get rid of Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 is still very new, and users with nvidia cards are having issues. 14.04 is a VERY stable operating system at this point. If you're a new Ubuntu user, I might suggest giving it a shot.

While nearly everyone wants to use the "latest and greatest" - with open soruce software that sometimes means tolerating small errors, or working to fix them. It sounds like you're getting the worst end of the problems with 16.04 and nvidia drivers.

Comment: He will have troubles with his GPU on 14.04, I even had much troubles with my GTX 750 Ti on 14.04

Comment: At least It will probably be not as bad as it was on 16.04.